# How to streamline different tables in Kable (w/ Latex)?

Tags: r, latex, kable, kableextra

I am trying to get these tables to look the same with width and text size. Would this be fixed if I found how to hang text in the columns? (Not sure how to accomplish that).

```
out_ibi1 <- kable(ibi1, "latex", booktabs = T,align = "lcccc",
                       digits = 2, linesep = "\\addlinespace") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("solid", "scale_down")) %>%
  save_kable(file="out1.pdf")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a specific size for each column (`column_spec`). In this case, you cannot use `scale_down`.

More information here: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf